# Can a c# service crash if there is a catch all

Tags: c#, exception, service

I have a service that is started using a start routine surrounded by a `try catch`  block as below.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Program.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error("Exception during Service Start");
        }
    }
```

Occasionally on some machines (1/100) it will occasionally print out the last line of `Program.Start` (a log message) and then fail with no log messages or event log messages. Should this be possible?

Thanks

EDIT: The service does kick off a few other threads but they are encapsulated in the same manner

EDIT: The Logger is a wrapper for log4net - it's working very reliably on a lot (100+) of machines (though yes it possibly the cause)

Comment: Does your service kick off any background threads?  If an unhandled exception occurs in one of those .NET will kill the process.

Comment: It could be your logger failing. What is "Logger" and what does it do?

Comment: do you use any COM components?

Comment: @Mitch - yes a couple of the threads that are started use COM Components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service could crash if an exception is thrown out of a started thread but not caught.

Are you adding a handler to each app domain unhandled exception?

eg:

```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler( CurrentDomain_UnhandledException );
```

EDIT
Also, you have the Application.ThreadException event which i forgot to mention:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

Comment: thanks yes I'm doing that on the first thread (should it also be done for the other threads?)

Comment: @Richard - I have edited the answer, I forgot to mention the Applicaiton.ThreadException event also. The Appdomain Unhandled exception should work for all threads

Comment: it's a service (rather than Windows Forms) so I'm not using the threadexception - correct me if that is the wrong?

Comment: No thats ok, I have written a windows service that just uses the AppDomain handler. I had a problem with random crashses and it turned out to be a problem with me starting a Thread, and exception was thrown back from the thread, but the method that started the tread did not have a try catch so the exception was thrown back and unhandled. Adding a try catch to the method that started the thread then caught the exception and handled it. I think the key is ensuring there is always a way to catch anything that is thrown back from a method.

Answer (score 2):

If the program crashes or an exception is thrown from try block, then for sure youll get Logger.Error log info but not the eventlog from system. If service crash or an unhandled exception occurs, then only eventlog on service is logged.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it could be possible. For instance, a StackOverflowException cannot be catched since .NET 2.0 (see [the MSDN article about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on your question but if you are asking whether your app can crash with a skeleton like that, the chances are very less. Since you have a catch all block almost all kinds of exceptions would be caught and thus your program would end gracefully.

How ever if its a repetive scenario that you are aware of it'd be better to handle it the known way then achieve what you want with an exception as generally execptions for times when something unknown might occur.

Comment: it happens only very occasionally on certain computers

Comment: Then i guess you should look at the other parts of your code just like others have suggested. If there are multiple threads and a conflict occurs in a related thread it could affect this, but its hard to say with a snippet

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the call to your Logger component in a try-catch block and let us know what happens? Are you able to monitor your service without the Logger component (i.e., based on whatever ouput the service is supposed to be produce - like DB updates)?

Try writing to the event log directly if the call to your Logger component fails. Put this in a try catch block as well. Since the Logger successfully wrote the last line in Program.Start(), it may be something related to unsuccessfully attempting to dispose a resource or something similar, and this is not getting logged.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the logger is wrappered in an try catch that's the main point of having my own class, sorry i didn't make that clear in the question.